# How to access websites resource files using web browsers console

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I have loaded a web page and now opened Chrome developers console. Now I want to read the resource files that website has loaded (like styles / images / language properties) in the web browser console. If it is possible to read what network calls made from console using Javascript code will also suffice.

(Actual implementation would be like:
I will be launching Chrome browser using Selenium and Java code and once launched I will execute Javascript code to get internationalisation file loaded over network for particular website so that I can adapt my Java selenium code base as per internationalisation language used.

URL : https://www.sapfioritrial.com/sites?helpset=trial&sap-client=001
Trying to get url of this **i18n_en.properties** file which can be seen in network tab but I need to get this using Javascript executed using Java Selenium code
)

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Resources" tab.  Under the "Frames" folder in the tree view on the left, you'll find a hierarchy of the files and clicking them lets you view the contents.

The "Network" tab lets you see all the resources accessed, and shows you the HTTP status (ie: 200, 404, 500, etc...), size, how long it took to download, and in what order the resources were loaded.

Comment: I wanted to access them from console tab using javascript code

Comment: Can you explain why, and what it is you expect to get out of doing so in Javascript that the developer tools don't give you?

Comment: Hello @Witchfinder,
I will be launching chrome browser using selenium and java code and once launched I want to get internalization file loaded for particular website so that I can adapt my java selenium code base as per internalization language used.

Comment: I suppose in vanilla JS, you could potentially use the DOM - document.getElementsByTagName or ById.  Iterate through them accessing the src element, and then construct an XMLHttpRequest() and read the file contents.  Sounds like more effort than it's worth though.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The network calls are available in the [network tab](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiQjof2wpXLAhVBc44KHScmAXEQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fdevtools%2Fdocs%2Fnetwork&usg=AFQjCNGQUsJoPUFP4G51QCN_iL29Lpnu7w&sig2=YITFHxpZC3_QG0IDpERLGg&cad=rja)

Comment: I wanted to access them from console tab using javascript code

Comment: @Santhosh_Reddy you could save them as HAR files ? Would that serve your purpose ?

Comment: Hello @AB Kolan,
I will be launching chrome browser using selenium and java code and once launched I want to get internalization file loaded for particular website so that I can adapt my java selenium code base as per internalization language used.